# How can we give email id already exist using php mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Code

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','123456') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('email') or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      extract($_POST);
      $sql=mysql_query("insert into user(name,email)value('$name','$email')");
      if($sql)
        {
          echo '<script>alert("successfull");</script>';
        }
      else
        {
          echo '<script>alert("error");</script>';
        }
   }
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" name="form">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

how can we insert data into database without duplicate email id after submit it show alert msg that email id already exist?

thank you

Comment: Write a select sql before insert to see if mail id exists.

Comment: Check if there is a entry with the email first, and then insert based on the result.

Comment: mark email id related column in table as unique column

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   extract($_POST);
   $query = mysql_query("select * from user where email = '$email'");
   $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
   if($result > 0 )
    {
      echo 'Email already exits';
    }
  else
    {
      // code here for insert or what ever you wants
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: then how do we insert into the database

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly the **`mysql_*` functions has been deprecated** as of PHP version 5.5.0 and above. So its greatly advised to use `mysqli_*` functions.

To answer your question, a simple select query along with if statements would do:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
    //Email Already Exists
}
else
{
    //Perform Insertion
}
```

Lastly, its highly recommended to **use prepared statements**.

Answer (score 0):

First make a select query to check whether on this email and name entry already exist or not.

```
$SelectSqlQry=mysql_query("select COUNT(email) from user where email = '.$email.'");
$LengthRecords = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectSqlQry);
if($LengthRecords > 0) {
     //do your alert or anything.  
     //alert email already exists.  
     echo '<script>alert("Email Already Exists");</script>'; 
}
else {
     //Insert email..
}
```

then check your condition on this variable. `SelectSqlQry`